# Splitting a SQL String per Command

Tags: c#, split

I have just discovered that SQL Server CE doesn't allow you to batch queries. So given a large string of SQL statements i'm trying to split them out and then execute them individually. The problem is that some queries are seperated by a single line and others 2. For examples say i have the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE [Settings] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [Settings] ADD
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Settings] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])

INSERT INTO [Settings] ([Name, [Value]) VALUES ('SiteUrl', 'http://localhost')
INSERT INTO [Settings] ([Name], [Value]) VALUES ('AssetsUrl', '/Assets')
```

I'd like to split each sql command into a string array. Appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Where are these queries defined?

Comment: Why is is a problem that queries are separated by 2 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code split you big meat sql string to separete sql commands

```
string str = @"CREATE TABLE [Settings] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [Settings] ADD
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Settings] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])

INSERT INTO [Settings] ([Name, [Value]) VALUES ('SiteUrl', 'http://localhost')
INSERT INTO [Settings] ([Name], [Value]) VALUES ('AssetsUrl', '/Assets')";

// Replace all [new line] to [space]
while (str.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
{
    str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");           
}

// Array of all sql commands using in query
string[] sqlCommands = { "CREATE TABLE", "ALTER TABLE", "INSERT INTO" };

// Insert before each sql expression new line
foreach (string sqlCommand in sqlCommands)
{
    str = str.Replace(sqlCommand, Environment.NewLine + sqlCommand);
}

// Split big sql string to separate commands, and remove empty strings
string[] arr = str.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
            StringSplitOptions.None);
arr = arr.Where(cmd => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd)).ToArray();

// Execute sql commands
foreach (string command in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(">> {0}{1}", command, Environment.NewLine);
}
```